# how to convert a date string to tm_wday in tm structure

Tags: c

I have a date string format say like "2010-03-01" and I want to get the "tm_wday" equivalent of it say like Monday, Tuesday ...

Could someone give me a hint on how to achieve this in c?

Answer (score 3):

Check the [`strptime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) function:

```
char *strptime(const char *s, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
```

> The strptime() function is the converse function to [strftime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) and converts the
>   character string pointed to by s to values which are stored in the tm  structure
>   pointed  to by tm, using the format specified by format.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mktime()` to calculate the weekday.

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  const char *p = "2010-03-01";
  struct tm t;
  memset(&t, 0, sizeof t);  // set all fields to 0
  if (3 != sscanf(p,"%d-%d-%d", &t.tm_year, &t.tm_mon, &t.tm_mday)) {
    ; // handle error;
  }
  // Adjust to struct tm references
  t.tm_year -= 1900;
  t.tm_mon--;
  // Calling mktime will set the value of tm_wday
  if (mktime(&t) < 0) {
    ; // handle error;
  }
  printf("DOW(%s):%d (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, ...)\n", p, t.tm_wday);
  // DOW(2010-03-01):1 (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, ...)
  return 0;
}
```